# Hackerrank "Queues: A Tale of Two Stacks" Javascript Solution

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, interview-questions, queue

Here is the [original problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-queue-using-two-stacks), and below is my solution (passing). It's asking to implement a queue with 2 stacks, which means I cannot simply use Array.shift. I wonder if the solution can be improved. Is there a better way than this to implement a queue with 2 stacks?

```
function processData(input) {
    var inputs = input.split('\n')
    var cmd;
    var inQueue = [],
        outQueue = []
    var len;

    function inQueueToOutQueue() {
        if (outQueue.length === 0) {
            len = inQueue.length;
            while (len-- > 0) {
                outQueue.push(inQueue.pop())
            }
        }
    }

    for (var i = 1, max = inputs[0]; i <= max; i++) {
        cmd = inputs[i].split(' ');
        switch (cmd[0]) {
            case '1':
                inQueue.push(cmd[1]);
                break;
            case '2':
                inQueueToOutQueue();
                outQueue.pop()
                break;
            case '3':
                inQueueToOutQueue();
                console.log(outQueue[outQueue.length - 1])
                break;
            default:
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pretty much nailed it.
You don't really need the `len` variable here though,
you could use a condition on `inQueue.length` directly.

> ```
> len = inQueue.length;
> while (len-- > 0) {
>     outQueue.push(inQueue.pop())
> }
> ```

The other thing I notice is the inconsistent use of semicolons.
Sometimes you add at the end of statements,
sometimes not.
You could choose whichever way, but do it consistently.

Lastly, the empty `default` statement of the `switch` is unnecessary, you can drop it.

Comment: Thanks! you mean `while (inQueue.length!==0)`?

Comment: @kdenz yes, that's what I meant!